# wp_get_attachment_image_sizes('large') prints small sizes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the following code to print out the srcset for my image:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_srcset' ) ) :?>
srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( get_post_thumbnail_id( $blog_results->post->ID, 'medium' ) ) ); ?>"
sizes="<?php  echo esc_attr(wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( get_post_thumbnail_id( $blog_results->post->ID, 'medium' ) ) ); ?>"
<?php endif; ?>
```

The container that I'm using has 350px width, however WordPress returns this:

```
sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"
```

I would like to enforce somehow to get the next available size because the image quality is really poor. I've been searching for a solution to this up until now but without success.

Is there any clean way I could accomplish this without hard coding "sizes"?

Answer (score 1):

you may be try this approach.

First:

```
//$name = Image size identifier.
//$width = Image width in pixels.
//$height = Image height in pixels.
//$crop =true/false (crop images to specified width and height or resize).
$name = 'custom-size'; $width = '350px'; $height = '200px'; $crop = true;
add_image_size($name, $width, $height, $crop);
```

check this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/.
this function write in functions.php file. now you can use this custom size image where you need.

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'wp_get_attachment_image_srcset' ) ) :?>
srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( get_post_thumbnail_id( $blog_results->post->ID, 'custom-size' ) ) ); ?>"
sizes="<?php  echo esc_attr(wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( get_post_thumbnail_id( $blog_results->post->ID, 'custom-size' ) ) ); ?>"
<?php endif; ?>
```

now you can get your desire image.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but it doesn't seem to work, at least not on my side.

Comment: Still couldn't find a solution to this problem except for hard-coding the sizes parameter. Did anyone use the above suggestion successfully? If yes, then probably there's something else preventing this in my setup.

Comment: I have the same problem. Please let us know if you find a solution to this! I'm hardcoding the sizes attribute as well (to gain full control, but obviously this should be automised in a smarter way.).

Answer (score 1):

For me this working for custom size:

```
add_image_size( 'custom_size', 350, 350 ); // here I add custom image size

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/45507581/3829187
function create_responsive_image( $img ) {
    $img_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $img );
    $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $img_id );
    $img_sizes = wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( $img_id, 'custom_size' ); // and here I use custom image size
    return '<img src="' . $img . '" srcset="' . esc_attr( $img_srcset ) . '" sizes="' . esc_attr( $img_sizes ) . '">';
}
```

Or if you don't want to create custom image size you can use other default WP img sizes: 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', 'full'. Default is 'medium' 300px

```
function create_responsive_image( $img ) {
    $img_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $img );
    $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $img_id );
    $img_sizes = wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( $img_id, 'full' ); // for full size for example
    return '<img src="' . $img . '" srcset="' . esc_attr( $img_srcset ) . '" sizes="' . esc_attr( $img_sizes ) . '">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to have been there for a while, and I had the same issue even today. I've done some digging and found out this was actually caused by theme's content width. Simply removing or re-setting theme's content width to a desired number will resolve the issue.

```
<?php
  // Look for the function setting content width, or create a new one in functions.php
  function mytheme_content_width() {
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'mytheme_content_width', 300 ); // Change 300 to a bigger number
  }
  add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_content_width', 0 ); // Or completely remove the action.
?>
```