# Wordpress: adding ‘srcset’ and ‘sizes’ attributes to image from customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, image, themes, srcset

`Wordpress` automatically adds `srcset` and `sizes` attributes to all images coming from posts. That’s very neat.

**But how to I get WordPress to add those attributes to images that come from a customizer input?**

In my case: a default image for posts. That default image is displayed when no image was uploaded in a post. It’s uploaded by the user through the customizer and called using `get_theme_mod`.

image from post (**works fine**, all attributes are added):

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'news', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
```

if no image is provided: the default image is loaded (**no ’scrset’ and ’sizes’**)

```
'<img src="' . esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'default_image' ) ) . '" alt="default image" class="img-responsive" />'
```

`wp_image_add_srcset_and_sizes()` seems to be the way to go but it requires attributes I don’t know where to get.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this function does the trick:

```
function create_responsive_image( $img ) {
  $img_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $img );
  $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $img_id );
  $img_sizes = wp_get_attachment_image_sizes( $img_id );
  return '<img src="' . $img . '" srcset="' . esc_attr( $img_srcset ) . '" sizes="' . esc_attr( $img_sizes ) . '">';
}
```